# When is a minimum distance decoder also a maximum likelihood decoder?

Tags: probability, coding-theory, information-theory, parameter-estimation

It is well known that if we have a binary symmetric channel with crossover probability $\epsilon<0.5$ and we send a word $x$ through it, the most likely word is the one with minimum hamming distance to the received word $y$, i.e. the received word itself. If we send a word from a codebook $C$ and we choose it uniformly at random then our best guess is the codeword closest in hamming distance to the received word:

$\hat x =\arg \min_{x\in C}\|x-y\|_1$

The same argumentation follows with the Gaussian channel but instead of minimizing the hamming distance the minimization is with respect to the $l_2$ distance. Then my question is:

Is it known for what binary input channels a minimum distance decoder is equivalent to a maximum likelihood decoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is a useful general characterization. One starts assuming that the intra-symbols errors and independent, and hence

$$L=\log p( {\bf y} | {\bf x}) = \sum_i \log p(y_i | x_i) $$

In the case of the binary symmetric channel, we have $\log p(y_i | x_i)= a + b \, d_i $ with $d_i = | x_i -y_i|$, $b=2 \epsilon -1 <0 $ and $a=1-\epsilon$. So $L = n a + b \sum d_i$ and it's enough to minimize $\sum d_i =\|{\bf x}-{\bf y}\|_1$

In the case of the gaussian, we have $\log p(y_i | x_i) = s + t \,d_i^2$ with $t<0$, and hence we want to minimize $\|{\bf x}-{\bf y}\|_2$

A (not very revealing, nor very general) generalization would be: if $\log p(y_i | x_i) =  g(|x_i-y_i|^k)$ with $g : {\mathbb R}_{\ge 0} \to {\mathbb R}$ monotonous decreasing, then the maximum likelihood estimator minimizes the $k$ distance $\hat x =\arg \min_{x\in C}\|x-y\|_k$

Comment: I was afraid that the answer would be the one that you gave. Probably it is quite hard to say anything more general, and from the point of view of channel theory it might not shed any more light...

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of error on a discrete memoryless channel $P(E)$ is strictly less than one half, then minimum distance decoding is equivalent to maximum likelihood decoding
$$P(E) = \sum r P(E|r)P(r)= \sum r P\left(v’=\frac{v}{r}\right)P(r)<0.5$$

Comment: Thanks for your input! Can you elaborate a little bit more on your argument?